# Reuse view template in different controllers in MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a **Book controller**, and an **Author controller**, inside Author, there is a request to get all books, now I already have a `Display Template` for the book sitting inside the Book controller, and would like to reuse it.... In cshtml, it's sort of easy:

```
@Html.Action("GetAuthorBooksBookBadge", "Book")
```

but if I want to call an Ajax function to return a list of books in string (Json) format, then I have to apply that action inside the controller code like this:

```
...
ArrayList books = new ArrayList();

// get books and add to the array in string format

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    books.Add(Utils.RenderRazorViewToString(ControllerContext, "DisplayTemplates/DisplayBookBadge", book)); // TODO: fix
}
...
```

Now as you can see, the **ControllerContext** does not belong in the right place.... I want to apply the Display Template inside the book controller, and return it as a string, how? I tried many ways where you create a controllercontext on the fly, create an instance of BookController...

Comment: without any changes to your code, would it not be a better idea to place this shared view in the shared views folder?? i may be missing the point totally here, so ignore if that's the case

Comment: any architectural suggestions are welcome. Putting it in shared folder kind of misses the point, because it really belongs to the Book controller. Im just requesting it from another controller.

Comment: This is a sad day, about a week since I posted this question, no answers :/